# Pytest multiple mock functions which calls from class constructor

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, pytest

My project has the files in the following structure

```
library
|
 ----- utils.py
 ----- core.py

Report
|
 ----- __init.py__

tests
|
 ----- test_report.py
```

There is a function to validate if an Excel sheet is available or not in an Excel file in the `utils.py` file

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def load_excel(file_workbook, sheetname):
    wb = load_workbook(file_workbook, read_only=True)
    if sheetname in wb.sheetnames:
        return True
    return False
```

In core.py,

```
from utils import load_excel
class Report:
     def __init__(self, input_file_path):
        self.inputFilePath = input_file_path
        xls = pd.ExcelFile(input_file_path) 
        self.df_input_consumption = pd.read_excel(
            xls, sheet_name="Sheet 1", header=[0]
        )
        
        if load_excel(input_file_path, "Sheet 2"):
               self.df_sheet2 = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name="Sheet 2", header= None)
               self.dict_sheet2 = self.get_sheet2()
               
    def choose_template(self):
        pass
```

In my test_report.py, I want to mock pd.ExcelFile, pd.read_excel and load_excel from utils module. This is my code.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
from unittest import mock
import pandas as pd
# import required module
import sys
  
# append the path of the
# parent directory
sys.path.append("../library")

import os

from core import Report

@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"DB_CONNECTION_STRING": "Mock_Connection_String", 
                              "DB_DATABASE": "Mock_Db", 
                              "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING": "Mock_Azure_connection_String" 
                              },clear=True)

@mock.patch("pandas.ExcelFile")
@mock.patch("pandas.read_excel")
@mock.patch("utils.load_excel")
def test_choose_template_valid(mocked_excel_file, mocked_read, mocked_load_excel):
    mocked_excel_file.return_value = ''
    
    mocked_read.side_effect = [
       pd.DataFrame({"test_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}),
       pd.DataFrame({"test_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}),
    ]
    mocked_load_excel.return_value = False
    
    
    expected = "fizz"
    report_obj = Report('./test.xlsx')

    report_obj.choose_template()
    actual = "fizz"
    assert actual == expected
```

Here I am expecting the load_excel should return False. But Its getting executed and executing `load_workbook` which is producing

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './test.xlsx'`

````
    if load_excel(input_file_path, "Sheet 2"):
../library/utils.py:459: in load_excel
    wb = load_workbook(file_workbook, read_only=True)
../../../../anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py:315: in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
../../../../anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py:124: in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
../../../../anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py:96: in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')```

Why It is failing even though I mocked `load_excel` function?
````

Comment: You have to mock "core.load_excel" instead of "utils.load_excel", see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I changed this line to True `mocked_load_excel.return_value = True` in test_report.py and expecting the control goes into reading the Sheet 2. But I am getting an empty value and the IF condition is falling. How can I make it as True? and It should read the Sheet 2

Comment: You got the order of the mock arguments mixed up. The nearest (e.g. last) mock decorator belongs to the first argument, so you need `mocked_load_excel, mocked_read, mocked_excel_file`.